# react-step-progress bar styling customization

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am creating a progress bar using the `react-step-progress[enter link description here][1]` library provided in react. It already takes it own styling reference from `react-step-progress/dist/index.css`. But, I want to override the colors provided by them. I tried to override by creating my own sass file and giving reference to those classes but they dont seem to override the existing styles.

Can someone please help me override those styles?

I had taken reference from the following link. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-step-progress?activeTab=readme

I have tried to override in the following way.
I imported my own scss file with the required styles I want in my tsx file.
Then I referred my respective classes in the progressbar tag like this.

**iconStyles.module.scss**

```
.ProgressBar {
.stepColor {
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color: #26890D;
  } 
}
```

And I have imported this class into my tsx file in the following way :

**Progressbar.tsx**

```
import styles from './iconStyles.module.scss';
import * as React from 'react';
import StepProgressBar from 'react-step-progress';

const step2Content = <h1>Step1</h1>;
const step3Content = <h1> Step 2</h1>;
const step4Content = <h1> Step3 </h1>;

export default function ProgressBar() {
  // setup step validators, will be called before proceeding to the next step

  function step2Validator() {
    // return a boolean
  }

  function step3Validator() {
    // return a boolean
  }

  // render the progress bar
  return (
    <div>
      <StepProgressBar
       className={styles.stepColor}
        startingStep={0}
        steps={[
          {
            label: 'Step1',
            name: 'Step1',
            content: step1Content
          },
          {
            label: 'Step2',
            name: 'Step2',
            content: step2Content,
            validator: step2Validator
          },
          {
            label: 'Step3',
            name: 'Step3',
            content: step3Content,
            validator: step3Validator
          }
        ]} onSubmit={undefined} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you could provide the relevant parts of the code you have tried so far :)

Comment: Yeah I added it accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

To control the class used for each step you need to use the `stepClass` prop rather than the `className` prop:

```
  [...]
  return (
    <div>
      <StepProgressBar
        stepClass={styles.stepColor}
        startingStep={0}
        steps={ [...] }
        onSubmit={undefined} />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Now as this is a progress bar, there would be varying colors for completed, active and next steps right. Can you let me know how can that be achieved as there is only one single element <StepProgressBar/> that we would be using. Can we give multiple class names in the stepClass prop?

Comment: And this actually hasn't overridden the original color that <StepProgressBar/> is providing.

Comment: There are a few props provided to customise the styles but they don't seem to be doing the job

Comment: @DSR I see you have nested your css selectors. Try flattening the structure by making sure that `.stepColor` isn't contained within `.ProgressBar`

Comment: Yeah sure I'll try this out thank you!